# Is it possible to data bind to local settings data?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, textblock

I would like to bind some TextBlock components to local settings data. Is this possible and, if so, how is the LocalSettings object referenced in XAML?

Comment: if you have an object you can just bind it to UI element by using Binding. I've done similar thing by creating temporary object with fields that I've needed

Comment: Yes, I've done that, too; my question is whether I can bind directly to local settings values.

Comment: i'm not sure that this is so simple question or a tricky one. but IMO it's the simple one. just take the value of textbox and set it for local settings value. Ofc it is possible if it has proper setter